# Updating the scrollbar after hiding an element

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a webpage, which contains sections. Each section has 100% width and height as well. My Section1 is on the top of the webpage. Section2 below Section1 and so on. For example my view is on the Section2 and I want to hide Section1. After Section1 is hidden, the Section2 is on the top. But the browser remembers, that it was below Section1 and scrolls one section down to Section3. So how should I avoid this scrolling?

```
    <section id="1">

    </section>
    <section id="2">

    </section>
    <section id="3">

    </section>

    <script type="text/javascript">
        <!--the view is on section2-->
        $('#1').addClass('hidden');
    </script>
```

Comment: post styles for hidden class.

Comment: How about using Location hash Property instead of hide?

Answer (score 1):

Let's start with a clarification:

> the browser remembers, that it was below Section1 and scrolls one
>   section down to Section3.

**The browser doesn't remember and doesn't scroll anything**. The browser was scrolled x pixels, and after removing the first section it is still scrolled x pixels, but the space that was occupied by section 2 is now occupied by section 3.

What you need to do is fix the vertical scroll to the position where it should be once the div `#1` is removed. As they occupy 100% height, it would be scrolling a negative value of `window.height`:

```
$(window).scrollTop( $(window).scrollTop() - $(window).height() );
```

Or if you want to scroll it to the beginning of the `#2` section, then you'd have to do this:

```
$(window).scrollTop( $("#2").offset().top );
```

You can see it working on this jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/7wegxuyu/4/ (it contains both examples, one is commented, you'd need to uncomment it to see it working)

Comment: I think FF and IE need to also be addressed with 'html' if window is not used to scroll?

Comment: Thanks. You are right, I corrected the code with your suggestion